# psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server failed: Operation timed out Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, psycopg2

I have created an DB instance as follows: [image]

[image]

with the security groups below. With the inbound rule set to my IP.
[image]

However when using :

```
import psycopg2
import logging
engine = psycopg2.connect(
    database="postgres",
    user="xxxxx",
    password="xxxxx",
    host="xxx.rds.amazonaws.com",
    port='5432'
)
```

I get the traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/samuelwilson/trading/aws_connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    engine = psycopg2.connect(
  File "/Users/samuelwilson/trade/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "xxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (3.223.2.177), port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

After then checking netstat for 5432, straight after running the script i get:

tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.15.54327     17.253.35.204.80       TIME_WAIT
tcp4       0      0  192.168.0.15.54329     17.253.35.203.80       TIME_WAIT
ee3b4653a1174d4b stream      0      0 ee3b46539fa87793                0                0                0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

But shortly after only:
ee3b4653a1174d4b stream      0      0 ee3b46539fa87793                0                0                0 /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432

Showing no tcp connection to 5432.

I have updated my postgresql.conf listen_addresses to '*' and pg_hba.conf i added the following:

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust

If IPv6:

host    all             all             ::/0                    trust

host    all             all             3.223.2.177             trust

If IPv4:

host    all             all             ::/0                    trust

If IPv4:

host    all             all             3.223.2.177             trust

'''

Comment: had the same error, is there any solution @Samuel Wilson